# Yii2. Открыть доступ к каталогу ко всем подкаталогам и файлам внутри него

Tags: php, yii2, .htaccess, apache

Подскажите, пожалуйста как открыть доступ к папке и ко всем подпапкам и файлам внутри нее.

Создал папку attachments в корне сайта (домен/public_html/attachments).

В файле .htaccess прописал:

```
RewriteRule ^attachments/.*$ - [F,L]
```

При запросе домен/attachments/ выдает:

> 403 Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /attachments/ on this server.

Подскажите, как правильно прописать доступ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 Forbidden выдается из-за настроек безопасности хостером, в случае, если отсутствует индексный файл в каталоге.